# Unexpected behavior of HDRI Lighting

Tags: rendering, lighting, hdri

I'm not sure if I'm experiencing some sort of bug or I'm missing something, but in some of my blend files the HDRI-s I use for lighting need to be turned up to a strength of around 200 to look proper in the rendered view, even though the same images work perfectly fine with a strength of 1 in other projects. Even worse, when I render as an EXR, the results opened in any other program appear overexposed to the point that they are just plain white. When I render with a strength of 1, I get somewhat proper results in other programs, but complete darkness inside of Blender. If I append the content of the project to another blend file, they work properly, but this came up multiple times already and it's quite a hurdle to set up a new project every time this happens.

[image]

Here's a side by side view of the render output inside blender and the same file opoened in Photoshop - This is with the hdri set to a very high strength.

[image]

Here's my world shader setup that resulted in the image above.

Link to the Blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ytu3WBe000t1bFrVV_C5kPkj3MjogzhL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add screenshots.

Comment: The issue here is likely to be something to do with compositing, color space, exposure, etc, all of which might be applied after the render but before the conversion to 0,1 (non EXR) color.  To start to troubleshoot this, we'd need to see the complete render properties, as well as any compositing, but of course an entire file, with packed .hdr, would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks, added link to the blend file to the post (hope the Drive link is a proper way to do that), deleted the smoke sim from the file but the issue can still be seen.

Comment: Okay, I found it! It was the exposure under color management in the render settings set to a value of -6. This was a setting that I wasn't even aware of, and I had the same issue in another file, so not sure how that change was made to it. Thanks for the tip for where to look.

Comment: No bug, your exposure is set to a pretty low value: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsvTX.gif